# How to change selector result within an "each" loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var elementSelector = 'select.myClass';
$(elementSelector).each(function(i){
    /*
     * if (several conditions return true) {
     */
        doSomeDOMChanges(); //Change the DOM and add several more <select class="myClass">
    /*
     * }
     */
});
```

Problem is, within that loop, `$(elementSelector)` is not reevaluated, and its' size remains the same throughout the entire loop. `$(elementSelector).length` for example would stay `18`, even though it actually increased to `20` within the 4th iteration.

My question is, how to force JQuery to re-select `$(elementSelector)` on the next iteration (without "resetting" the loop / repeating previous iterations, of course).

Thank you.

Comment: You don't.  I would suggest putting the logic in a method, and if the count of the elements changes, terminate the loop and call the method again.

Comment: Otherwise, you could potentially select the elements and push them to an array.  Change your logic to function while the array is not empty, removing the elements it processes.  Then new elements would simply be pushed to the array.

Comment: @Taplar thanks, I thought of something like that, I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way

Comment: Not with regards to changing the original selection.  The logic for `each()` performs an internal for loop, with the length stored as a local variable before the loop starts.  Nothing you do to the element will cause that variable to change.  [For reference](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.each)

Comment: from a maintenance and debugging point of view, this kind of code is a nightmare, I even think that it deserves a deletion

Answer (score 1):

mark used classes with an attribute or some class, and select which are not used

```
var elementSelector = $('select.myClass:not[data-used=1]');
$(elementSelector).each(function(i){

    $(this).data('used', 1)
    if (several condition return true) {
        doSomeDOMChanges(); //Change the DOM and add several more <select class="myClass">
     }


});
```

Comment: You left out the logic that makes use of the data value, and selects the new elements

Answer (score 1):

If it is guaranteed that the modified DOM content occurs *further* in the document than the element that you are currently visiting in the loop, then you could rely on DOM methods that return a *live* NodeList, such as:

- `getElementsByTagName`
- `getElementsByClassName`
- `getElementsByName`
- `children`

Here is a demo where the DOM is extended with one more `select` element, when the value of the current `select` element has less than 5 characters. The newly inserted `select` element will have options which have values that are 1 character longer.

```js
function doSomeDOMChanges(select) {
    $(select).after($("<select>").addClass("myClass").append(
        $("<option>").text($(select).val() + "0"),
        $("<option>").text($(select).val() + "1"),
        $("<option>").text($(select).val() + "2")
    ));
}

for (var select of document.getElementsByTagName("select")) {
    if ($(select).is(".myClass")) {
        if ($(select).val().length < 5) {
            doSomeDOMChanges(select);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myClass">
    <option>2
    <option selected>3
    <option>5
</select>
```

The downsides:

- You cannot get such a live collection from a call to `$()`, using the power of a CSS selector
- It only works when the DOM changes are further in the document. If changes are made in content that is already "behind" the currently iterated element, the loop will not work as expected, as the new DOM element is inserted in the live collection *before* the currently iterated element, meaning it will not be visited, and maybe even worse: the current element will move to a higher index in that collection and be visited again by the loop.

If one of these points is a problem, you could just make the jQuery selection again, and keep a Set of the elements you had already visited. The next demo makes DOM changes *before* the currently visited element:

```js
function doSomeDOMChanges(select) {
    $(select).before($("<select>").addClass("myClass").append(
        $("<option>").text($(select).val() + "0"),
        $("<option>").text($(select).val() + "1"),
        $("<option>").text($(select).val() + "2")
    ));
}

let visited = new WeakSet;
let selector = "select.myClass";
for (let more = true; more; null) {
    more = false;
    $(selector).each(function() {
        if (visited.has(this)) return;
        visited.add(this);
        if ($(this).val().length < 5) {
            doSomeDOMChanges(this);
            more = true;
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myClass">
    <option>2
    <option selected>3
    <option>5
</select>
```